# how I insert JSON data into Apex class

Tags: json, class, casting

I have a question about convert the JSON to class and insert and see the Data from standard Account Salesforce (account, contact)

---

### This is the serialized data

```json
{
  "conList": [
    {
      "title": "Sample Title1",
      "phone": "01011111111",
      "name": "Sample Contact1",
      "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc1111111111"
    },
    {
      "title": "Sample Title2",
      "phone": "01022222222",
      "name": "Sample Contact2",
      "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc2222222222"
    },
    {
      "title": "Sample Title3",
      "phone": "01033333333",
      "name": "Sample Contact3",
      "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc3333333333"
    },
    {
      "title": "Sample Title4",
      "phone": "01044444444",
      "name": "Sample Contact4",
      "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc4444444444"
    },
    {
      "title": "Sample Title5",
      "phone": "01055555555",
      "name": "Sample Contact5",
      "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc5555555555"
    },
    {
      "title": "Sample Title6",
      "phone": "01066666666",
      "name": "Sample Contact6",
      "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc6666666666"
    },
    {
      "title": "Sample Title7",
      "phone": "01077777777",
      "name": "Sample Contact7",
      "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc7777777777"
    },
    {
      "title": "Sample Title8",
      "phone": "01088888888",
      "name": "Sample Contact8",
      "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc8888888888"
    },
    {
      "title": "Sample Title9",
      "phone": "01099999999",
      "name": "Sample Contact9",
      "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc9999999999"
    },
    {
      "title": "Sample Title10",
      "phone": "0101010101010101010",
      "name": "Sample Contact10",
      "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc10101010101010101010"
    }
  ],
  "accList": [
    {
      "type": "Installation Partner",
      "phone": "01011111111",
      "name": "Account Sample1",
      "industry": "Technology",
      "billingAddress": "Sample Address1",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc1111111111"
    },
    {
      "type": "Installation Partner",
      "phone": "01022222222",
      "name": "Account Sample2",
      "industry": "Technology",
      "billingAddress": "Sample Address2",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc2222222222"
    },
    {
      "type": "Installation Partner",
      "phone": "01033333333",
      "name": "Account Sample3",
      "industry": "Technology",
      "billingAddress": "Sample Address3",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc3333333333"
    },
    {
      "type": "Installation Partner",
      "phone": "01044444444",
      "name": "Account Sample4",
      "industry": "Technology",
      "billingAddress": "Sample Address4",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc4444444444"
    },
    {
      "type": "Installation Partner",
      "phone": "01055555555",
      "name": "Account Sample5",
      "industry": "Technology",
      "billingAddress": "Sample Address5",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc5555555555"
    },
    {
      "type": "Installation Partner",
      "phone": "01066666666",
      "name": "Account Sample6",
      "industry": "Technology",
      "billingAddress": "Sample Address6",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc6666666666"
    },
    {
      "type": "Installation Partner",
      "phone": "01077777777",
      "name": "Account Sample7",
      "industry": "Technology",
      "billingAddress": "Sample Address7",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc7777777777"
    },
    {
      "type": "Installation Partner",
      "phone": "01088888888",
      "name": "Account Sample8",
      "industry": "Technology",
      "billingAddress": "Sample Address8",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc8888888888"
    },
    {
      "type": "Installation Partner",
      "phone": "01099999999",
      "name": "Account Sample9",
      "industry": "Technology",
      "billingAddress": "Sample Address9",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc9999999999"
    },
    {
      "type": "Installation Partner",
      "phone": "0101010101010101010",
      "name": "Account Sample10",
      "industry": "Technology",
      "billingAddress": "Sample Address10",
      "AccountNumber": "Acc10101010101010101010"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### What I have is

```java
public class jsonToSalesforce {
    //public Blob myfile{get;set;}
    public accRecord reports;
    public jsonToSalesforce(){
        reports = new accRecord();
    }
    public void doUpload() {
        //System.debug('myfile'+myfile.toString());
        reports = (accRecord) System.JSON.deserialize('{"conList":[{"title":"Sample Title1","phone":"01011111111","name":"Sample Contact1","description":"JSON Handling Practice","AccountNumber":"Acc1111111111"},{"title":"Sample Title2","phone":"01022222222","name":"Sample Contact2","description":"JSON Handling Practice","AccountNumber":"Acc2222222222"},{"title":"Sample Title3","phone":"01033333333","name":"Sample Contact3","description":"JSON Handling Practice","AccountNumber":"Acc3333333333"},{"title":"Sample Title4","phone":"01044444444","name":"Sample Contact4","description":"JSON Handling Practice","AccountNumber":"Acc4444444444"},{"title":"Sample Title5","phone":"01055555555","name":"Sample Contact5","description":"JSON Handling Practice","AccountNumber":"Acc5555555555"},{"title":"Sample Title6","phone":"01066666666","name":"Sample Contact6","description":"JSON Handling Practice","AccountNumber":"Acc6666666666"},{"title":"Sample Title7","phone":"01077777777","name":"Sample Contact7","description":"JSON Handling Practice","AccountNumber":"Acc7777777777"},{"title":"Sample Title8","phone":"01088888888","name":"Sample Contact8","description":"JSON Handling Practice","AccountNumber":"Acc8888888888"},{"title":"Sample Title9","phone":"01099999999","name":"Sample Contact9","description":"JSON Handling Practice","AccountNumber":"Acc9999999999"},{"title":"Sample Title10","phone":"0101010101010101010","name":"Sample Contact10","description":"JSON Handling Practice","AccountNumber":"Acc10101010101010101010"}],"accList":[{"type":"Installation Partner","phone":"01011111111","name":"Account Sample1","industry":"Technology","billingAddress":"Sample Address1","AccountNumber":"Acc1111111111"},{"type":"Installation Partner","phone":"01022222222","name":"Account Sample2","industry":"Technology","billingAddress":"Sample Address2","AccountNumber":"Acc2222222222"},{"type":"Installation Partner","phone":"01033333333","name":"Account Sample3","industry":"Technology","billingAddress":"Sample Address3","AccountNumber":"Acc3333333333"},{"type":"Installation Partner","phone":"01044444444","name":"Account Sample4","industry":"Technology","billingAddress":"Sample Address4","AccountNumber":"Acc4444444444"},{"type":"Installation Partner","phone":"01055555555","name":"Account Sample5","industry":"Technology","billingAddress":"Sample Address5","AccountNumber":"Acc5555555555"},{"type":"Installation Partner","phone":"01066666666","name":"Account Sample6","industry":"Technology","billingAddress":"Sample Address6","AccountNumber":"Acc6666666666"},{"type":"Installation Partner","phone":"01077777777","name":"Account Sample7","industry":"Technology","billingAddress":"Sample Address7","AccountNumber":"Acc7777777777"},{"type":"Installation Partner","phone":"01088888888","name":"Account Sample8","industry":"Technology","billingAddress":"Sample Address8","AccountNumber":"Acc8888888888"},{"type":"Installation Partner","phone":"01099999999","name":"Account Sample9","industry":"Technology","billingAddress":"Sample Address9","AccountNumber":"Acc9999999999"},{"type":"Installation Partner","phone":"0101010101010101010","name":"Account Sample10","industry":"Technology","billingAddress":"Sample Address10","AccountNumber":"Acc10101010101010101010"}]}', accRecord.class);
        List<accData> rec = new List<accData>();
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        for(accData c :rec){
            accList.add(new Account(Type=c.Type, Phone=c.Phone,
                                    Name=c.Name, Industry= c.Industry,
                                    BillingStreet=c.MailingStreet,
                                    BillingCity=c.MailingCity,
                                    BillingState=c.MailingState,
                                    BillingCountry=c.MailingCountry,
                                    BillingPostalCode=c.MailingPostalCode,
                                    AccountNumber=c.AccountNumber));
        }
        insert accList;        
    }
    
    // public class fromJSON{
    //     public cls_accdata accdata{get;set;}
    // }
    public class accRecord {
        public List<accData> acct = new List<accData>();
    }
    //record.accData.tmp.tmp.data;
    public class accData {
        public String Type; //{get;set;}
        public String Phone;        
        public String Name;    
        public String Industry;
        public String MailingStreet;
        public String MailingCity;
        public String MailingState;
        public String MailingCountry;
        public String MailingPostalCode;
        public String AccountNumber;
        //public List<DummyData> tmp;      
    }
    /*public class DummyData{
        public String data;
        public Dummy tmp;
    }
    public class Dummy{
        public String data;
    }
    */
}
```

---

Sorry about massive lines but please help this little newbie developer. Thank you

Comment: Hi Sheldon. Welcome to Salesforce StackExchange. You've included some example code but it's unclear to me what your exact issue is? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

your code is almost complete. You are missing some little things. Let's start from the class for the AccRecord that as to be as following

```
public class AccRecord {
    public List<accData> contList {get;set;};
}
public class AccData {
    public String type {get;set;};
    public String phone {get;set;};        
    public String name {get;set;};    
    public String industry {get;set;};
    public String mailingStreet {get;set;};
    public String mailingCity {get;set;};
    public String mailingState {get;set;};
    public String mailingCountry {get;set;};
    public String mailingPostalCode {get;set;};
    public String accountNumber {get;set;};   
}
```

The `{get;set;}` is needed to set and get the properties by the dot notation, if you want to instantiate some default value you have the define the constructor into the class as follows

```
public class NewClass {
    public String stringProp {get;set;}; // now null
    public Boolean booleanProp {get;set;}; // now null    
    
    /** when you runs NewClass object = new NewClass("foo") the object 
    will have stringProp equals to "foo" 
    and booleanProp equals to false.
    You can modify them by the dot notation, i.e. object.stringProp = "bar"
    */
    public newClass(String str) {
      this.stringProp = str;
      this.booleanProp = false;
    }
}
```

Finally when you want to serialize your data, let's suppose it is in the variable `data`, you have to runs the following code

```
AccRecord records = (AccRecord) System.JSON.deserialize(data, AccRecord.class)
// to write the data in the account you have to run the following lines
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
for(AccData dt : records) {
  accList.add(new Account(Type=dt.Type, Phone=dt.phone,
                                Name=dt.name, Industry= dt.industry,
                                BillingStreet=dt.mailingStreet,
                                BillingCity=dt.mailingCity,
                                BillingState=dt.mailingState,
                                BillingCountry=dt.mailingCountry,
                                BillingPostalCode=dt.mailingPostalCode,
                                AccountNumber=dt.accountNumber));
}
```

One last thing to notice is that your input data has to have the Address fields has to be already divided in the five fields you need, i.e. MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingCountry, MailingPostalCode. So you have to write you data as following

```
{
   "conList": [{
     "title": "Sample Title1",
     "phone": "01011111111",
     "name": "Sample Contact1",
     "mailingStreet": "Street 1",
     "mailingCity": " Milan",
     "mailingState": "Lombardy",
     "mailingCountry": "City",
     "mailingPostalCode": "20100",
     "description": "JSON Handling Practice",
     "accountNumber": "Acc1111111111"}]
 }
```

and finally check the capital letter in your definition of the properties of your classes.

What I have written before are the ingredients you need to parse a json, let's now compose them yourself :)

Comment: OP seems to suggest address is on `accList` elements, not `conList` elements.  And, if JSON can't be changed, some parser for a single multi-line string `billingAddress` into `BillingStreet, BillingCity, etc will be needed

Comment: I took we we wrote anche actually if you have an address that is made only by a single string you cannot parse it in the the right fields unless you define a standard, e.g. separated by o comma like "billingStreet, billingiCity..."